# Read content of nested template

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

How can I get JS access to `.content` of nested `<template>`?

I am trying to extend `<template>` with my [`imported-template`](https://github.com/Juicy/imported-template) element (which fetches template content from external file) and I would like to implement `<imported-content>` in similar manner to native `<content>`. To do so, I simply try

```
this.content.querySelector("imported-content")
```

but it occurred, that for nested template `this.content` is empty.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var XHTMLPrototype = Object.create((HTMLTemplateElement || HTMLElement).prototype);
        XHTMLPrototype.attachedCallback = function() {
            //..
            var distributeHere = this.content.querySelector("imported-content");
            var importedContent = document.createElement("span");
            importedContent.innerHTML = "Imported content";
            distributeHere.parentNode.replaceChild(importedContent, distributeHere);
        }

        document.register('imported-template', {
            prototype: XHTMLPrototype,
            extends: "template"
        });
    })();
</script>
<template id="fails" bind>
    <ul>
        <template is="imported-template" bind="{{ appdata }}">
            <li>
                <imported-content></imported-content>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/6tKL3/2/)

I am not sure if it is a bug, a design issue, or just template shim limitation.

I thought that maybe I am checking it in wrong life-cycle callback, so I tried `MutationObserver` [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/6tKL3/4/), but mutation does not occur as well.

Comment: Can you simplify your code? It seems as though it's doing a bunch of things, many of which don't have to do with the problem you're having. The simpler your code is the easier it is for us to understand what you're trying to do, what you want to happen, and what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

I [changed](http://jsfiddle.net/6tKL3/5/) your selector to `this.content.querySelector("[is='imported-content']")`. Is this what your trying to do?

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to get <imported-content>` Element